# how can reactjs access session data(username) from django

Tags: python, django, session, reactjs

i am using django with reactjs, and now i have maintained session and want to access session data by reactjs to cutomise UI.
what all can i do for this?

```
//my models.py snippet

class Users(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bg = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    badges = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    dob = models.DateField()
    contact = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    age = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)




//my views.py snippet

def login(request):
    print(request.POST.get('username'))
    username=str(request.POST.get('username'))
    password=str(request.POST.get('password'))

    if(Users.objects.filter(password=password, username=username).exists()):
        request.session['username'] = username
        name=request.session['username']
        return render(request, 'loggedin.html', {"username" : name})
    else:
        return HttpResponse("incorrect data")
```

Comment: just a suggestion.. dont mix react and django for front end development.. use on react/redux on front side and maybe django-rest on backend. I had lot of trouble while working on a project which involved this scenario and had to eventually move towards using completely react on front end.

Comment: You can use the Django Rest Framework to make an endpoint which responds with the user info - the endpoint receives the normal Request object, so you can just return request.user.username, etc.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do this is by following the [django-react-template](https://github.com/scottwoodall/django-react-template) from Scott Woodall on GitHub.
Basically, his approach to this is to **stuff the user-request data into Django's 'base.html'** (in the project it is called app.html) which is served by the backend (Django)

On the frontend side, he is accessing the data via the 'window' object.

```
{% load static %}
<!-- This is basically the ONLY webpage created in Django
see the window.django = {} part where variables are handed over initially to React
top most the Django CSRF Token
is this secure in Production?
...
...
-->

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Django & React Starter</title>
        ...
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>This application requires javascript to function.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="{% static "js/vendor.bundle.js" %}"></script>
        <script>
        window.django = {
            csrf: "{{ csrf_token }}",
            urls: {
                logout: "{% url "logout" %}",
                staticRoot: "{% static "" %}",
                users: "{% url "emailuser-list" %}"
            },
            user: {
                username: "{{ request.user.username }}",
                full_name: "{{ request.user.get_full_name }}",
                last_login: "{{ request.user.last_login }}",
                permissions: immutable.Set(
                    {% autoescape off %}JSON.parse('{{ permissions }}'){% endautoescape %}
                )
            }
        };
        </script>
        <script src="{% static "js/bundle.js" %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**All credits to Scott Woodall o/** I hope that gets you started!

Comment: This is what we do in our apps and it works really well. Initially we thought about calling the server for a chunk of JSON when our js apps had initialised, but that worked too convoluted. This approach is simple and it works perfectly.